# Managing SwiftUI state in a typical list -> details app

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm building an app that's similar in structure to the Apple [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/handling-user-input). My app has a `ListView`, which navigates to a `DetailsView`. The `DetailsView` is composed of a `UIKit` custom `UIView`, which I wrap with a `UIViewRepresentable`. So far, so good.

Now I have for now a list (let's say, of addresses) that I instantiate in memory, to be replaced with core data eventually. I'm able to bind (using `@EnvironmentObject`) the `List<Address>` to the `ListView`.

Where I'm stuck is binding the elements for each `DetailsView`. The Apple tutorial, referenced above, does something which I think isn't great - for some reason (that I can't figure out), it:

1. Binds the `List` to the details view (using `@EnvironmentObject`)
2. Passes the element (in the Apple tutorial case, `landmark`, in my case, an `address`) to the details view
3. During updating in response to a user gesture, it effectively searches the `List` for the element, to update the element in the list. This seems expensive especially if the list is large.

Here's the code for #3 which to me is suspect:

```
    Button(action: {
        self.userData.landmarks[self.landmarkIndex].isFavorite.toggle()
    })
```

In their code, `self.landmarkIndex` does a linear search:

```
    var landmarkIndex: Int {
        userData.landmarks.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == landmark.id })!
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is to bind the element directly to the `DetailsView` and have updates to the element update the list. So far, I have been unable to achieve this.

Does anyone know the right way? It seems like the direction the tutorial is pointing to does not scale.

Comment: Yeah, first time I did the tutorial, didn't even notice this step was odd.  Then after trying to get `@Binding` to work on my own project, I went back to the tutorial to see how they did it and they don't even use bindings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a `Landmark` object, you can pass a `Binding<Landmark>`.

LandmarkList.swift: Change the iteration from `userData.landmark` to their indices so you can get the binding. Then pass the bidding into `LandmarkDetail` and `LandmarkRow`

```
struct LandmarkList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Toggle(isOn: $userData.showFavoritesOnly) {
                    Text("Show Favorites Only")
                }

                ForEach(userData.landmarks.indices) { index in
                    if !self.userData.showFavoritesOnly || self.userData.landmarks[index].isFavorite {
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: LandmarkDetail(landmark: self.$userData.landmarks[index])
                                .environmentObject(self.userData)
                        ) {
                            LandmarkRow(landmark: self.$userData.landmarks[index])
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Landmarks"))
        }
    }
}
```

LandmarkDetail.swift: Change `landmark` into `Binding<Landmark>` and toggle the favorite based on the binding

```
    @Binding var landmark: Landmark
.
.
.
                    Button(action: {
                        self.landmark.isFavorite.toggle()
                    }) {
                        if self.landmark
                            .isFavorite {
                            Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.yellow)
                        } else {
                            Image(systemName: "star")
                                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                        }
                    }
```

LandmarkRow.swift: Change landmark to a `Binding`

```
@Binding var landmark: Landmark
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of approach to use binding directly to model `Address` item

Assuming there is view model like, where `Address` is `Identifiable` struct

```
class AddressViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var addresses: [Address] = []
}
```

So somewhere in `ListView` u can use the following

```
ForEach (Array(vm.addresses.enumerated()), id: \.element.id) { (i, address) in
    NavigationLink("\(address.title)", 
       destination: DetailsView(address: self.$vm.addresses[i])) // pass binding !!
}
```